# Node.js instances running in virtual machines and within primary web server

Tags: node.js, websocket, socket.io

I'm reasonably versed on the **Node.js** programming paradigm for asynchronous, event-driven, non-blocking programming model. I'm now trying to understand just how far I can extend the use of **Node.js** within a cloud computing ecosystem of virtual machines.

On the server side of my web dashboards, I have Node.js running as the http server and interacting with a Cassandra database. The user interacts with our cloud service through the browser dashboards. Websockets opened up between the client and server will allow server-side initiation of actions into the user's dashboard.

Part of the user's task activities will be to spawn cloud-based virtual machines for workflow activities.  These VMs will be executing applications that need to be interacting with the system's main Cassandra database.

I would very much like to have some feedback on the following **Node.js** architecture scenario:

When a virtual machine is spawned by a user, the ***VM is started with a Node.js instance*** running on the VM.  That ***VM's Node.js instance actively opens up a web socket with the system's primary Node.js  instance*** that is running or assigned (perhaps there are multiple Node.js instances available to communicate with the Cassandra database) to this VM, i.e. a ***Node-to-Node websocket is established*** from the VM's Node.js instance.

The VM's Node.js instance sets up a series of events to be watching for inside of the VM.  The system's Node.js instance has also set up a series of events to be watching for from the VM's Node.js instance.  When the VM's Node.js instance events are triggered completed, then the needed Cassandra DB actions are initiated and completed.  The system's Node.js instance is also monitoring for certain events from the VM to also initiate Cassandra DB actions.

In effect, what I am asking here is: ***does it make sense to establish Node.js-2-Node.js communication channels over websockets with both Node instances talking to the same backend DB?***

In this configuration, it would seem that I am able to set up a highly flexible, bi-directional, VM event tether that can watch/listen to prescribed events with DB recorded actions from both the system's Node.js instance and the VM's Node.js instance.

Is what I am describing here an atypical and nonsensical scenario?  Is there a better way to use Node.js in this use case?  Is there a more appropriate component configuration?

Kind regards, Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The purpose of the WebSocket HTTP extension is to enable two-way communication with the web-browser that is hidden behind firewall. The WebSocket replaces pulling schemes that were custom built on top of usual HTTP requests.

In your case it makes more sense just to make both Node.js instances to communicate with each other by sending usual REST requests.

Plus, I would consider making only one Node.js instance to communicate with the database and make all other instance to communicate through it. That way you will simplify the deployment of Node.js on your VMs. Plus making all data flowing through one server will make it easier to debug complex business logic.

Another disadvantage of using WebSocket is having a lot of opened connections. It seems that in your case most of the time most of your Node.js instances will be dormant. There is no point to keep connections with them.

Comment: OK...this makes sense.  So, would you use RESTify from the VM Node instance to initiate the REST requests to the primary Node.js instance?

Comment: Yes. Just send a REST request to your primary Node.js server.

Answer (score 1):

No, it does not.

The WebSocket protocol is only useful inasmuch as it allows web browsers which support WebSocket to communicate with a server application. It is not particularly interesting or useful otherwise, and should not be used for communications that don't involve a web browser.

Use normal TCP sockets (using the [net](http://nodejs.org/api/net.html) module) for server-to-server communication.